# Why is $ \arccos\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)= -2\arctan(x)$ true $\forall x\in (-\infty, 0]$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the problem that follows, and I'd appreciate any feedback on my solution in order to improve it. Thank you.

$$ \arccos\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right) = -2\arctan(x) $$

So, I start off with analysing the domain. It's clear that arctan is defined for all values of x that are a member of the real numbers.

We can also see that the argument of arccos is less than 1 and greater than -1 for all x's. So that means, our equation is defined for all x's that belongs to the real numbers.

$$\Rightarrow \tan(\arccos(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}) = \tan(-2\arctan(x))$$

Using the fact that $\tan(x) = \sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}/\cos(x)$ as well as $\tan(2x) = \frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$. I land at this equation:

$$\frac{|2x|}{1-x^2} = \frac{-2x}{1-x^2}$$

Which is true for all negative x's, so basically $\forall x\in (-\infty, 0]$

I'm now asking you whether I can deduce this is true. Because, I actually applied tan to both sides, so does this imply that the solution set also holds for our original equation, and is there a way to deduce this, maybe using estimations?

Thank you.

Comment: In your case, to prove that $f(x)=g(x)$ you could prove that $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x)=g'(x)$...

Comment: Yes that's true, but I wanted to try out the problem without using derivatives this time, to see what I have to consider in such a calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that the range for $\arctan x$ is $\left(-\frac \pi 2,\frac \pi 2\right)$ and therefore the range for $-2\arctan x$ is $\left(-\pi ,\pi \right)$ but the range for $\arccos\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)$ is $\left[0 ,\pi \right]$ therefore equality can possibly hold only for the range $\left[0,\pi \right)$ which implies $x\in(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I thought I needed.

Comment: @Tanamas You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your equation $\def\acos{\operatorname{acos}}$
$\def\atan{\operatorname{atan}}$

$$\acos\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2} = -2\atan x \tag{1}$$
And taking $\cos$ on both sides we get
$$(1)\ \implies\ \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2} = \cos (2\atan x) \tag{2}$$

Notice that it's only an implication, and for what you are trying to show you'll need the *other* direction, so you must be carful and check whether it's an equivalence or not, or for which $x'$s it's an equivalence.

One common problem in such treatments can be that the trigonometric functions do not have inverses; they do only have inverse functions when restrict to, say, small enough intervals.  This is usually referred to as *"taking a specific [branch of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts)"*.  For example, the usual choice for $\acos$ is a branch that satisfies $\acos x\in[0,2\pi]$, however it's totally legal, and depending on your problem might even be better, to have $\acos x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ for example.  Of cource you'll have to make clear in a paper or in a software which branch you are using when you are deviating from common notation.

To proceed with (2), observe that
$$\tan^2x
= \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}
= \frac{1-\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}
\qquad\text{thus}\qquad
\cos^2x = \frac1{1+\tan^2x}
\tag{3}$$
Substituting $x\mapsto \atan x$ turns (3) into

$$ \cos^2(\atan x) = \frac1{1+x^2} \tag{4}$$
Using the well known $\cos(2x) = \cos^2x - \sin^2x$, and using $\sin^2 + \cos^2=1$ to get a formula similar to (4) for $\sin^2$, we can finally write (2) as:

$$
\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}
= \underbrace{\cos^2(\atan x)}_{\tfrac1{1+x^2}} - \underbrace{\sin^2(\atan x)}_{\textstyle 1-\frac1{1+x^2}}
$$

and we are done.